# Round to nearest integer non-zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to come up with a crafty and "nice-looking" way of rounding to the nearest NON-ZERO whole number (I will only ever have positive integers). Three restraints I have are:

1. Must be a non-UDF solution as I will have some users who will want to trace formulas. Even though a VBA solution will result in a cleaner entry in the formula bar, they are not easily traceable by "front-end" users.
2. Some of the cells I am looking to round are quite long formulas themselves.

   - Think something like `=(SUMPRODUCT((A1:A20),(B1:B20)) / SUMPRODUCT((A21:A40),(B21:B40))) - (SUMPRODUCT((A41:A60),(B41:B60)) * SUMPRODUCT((A61:A80),(B61:B80))) + SUMPRODUCT((A81:A100),(B81:B100))`
   - I am unable to round the values in A1:B100 to make it whole numbers to begin with.
3. I am unable to use the cells with my formulas as a reference due to how the sheet must be styled for users. (e.g. I can only have one column of visible cells with my results. Therefore, if I used the formula cells as a reference, the formula cells would have to be hidden. This breaks restraint #1 because users would have difficulty with formula tracing.) This restraint is described in more detail below.

The most succinct formula I can think of is thus:

```
=IF(AND(C1 > 0, C1 < 1), ROUNDUP(C1, 0), ROUND(C1, 0))
```

Due to #3, I cannot use C1 as a reference. So my end result would be more like:

`=IF(AND((SUMPRODUCT((A1:A20),(B1:B20)) / SUMPRODUCT((A21:A40),(B21:B40))) - (SUMPRODUCT((A41:A60),(B41:B60)) * SUMPRODUCT((A61:A80),(B61:B80))) + SUMPRODUCT((A81:A100),(B81:B100)) > 0, (SUMPRODUCT((A1:A20),(B1:B20)) / SUMPRODUCT((A21:A40),(B21:B40))) - (SUMPRODUCT((A41:A60),(B41:B60)) * SUMPRODUCT((A61:A80),(B61:B80))) + SUMPRODUCT((A81:A100),(B81:B100)) < 1), ROUNDUP((SUMPRODUCT((A1:A20),(B1:B20)) / SUMPRODUCT((A21:A40),(B21:B40))) - (SUMPRODUCT((A41:A60),(B41:B60)) * SUMPRODUCT((A61:A80),(B61:B80))) + SUMPRODUCT((A81:A100),(B81:B100)), 0), ROUND((SUMPRODUCT((A1:A20),(B1:B20)) / SUMPRODUCT((A21:A40),(B21:B40))) - (SUMPRODUCT((A41:A60),(B41:B60)) * SUMPRODUCT((A61:A80),(B61:B80))) + SUMPRODUCT((A81:A100),(B81:B100)), 0))`

Not very "nice-looking".

Any recommendations?

Comment: I don't understand the motivation behind CONSTRAINT #3. Specifically, "...due to how the sheet must be styled for users". You're painting yourself into a corner and then want to find a way to the door without stepping on to the paint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**  *Overly complex formulas removed*

Another, simpler option

```
=MAX(1,ROUND(your_formula,0))
```

My formula assumes that `your_formula` will only return a positive value.  If that is not the case, please clarify what results you expect for zero or negative results.

**EDIT**

With regard to possible zero values, try this. I cannot test it since I am not at computer:

```
=--(TEXT(your_formula, "[>1]0;[>0]1;0"))
```

Comment: @pnuts I don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: It returns a `1`.  The closest non-zero integer.   It will return `1` for any value less than `1`, and OP indicated that we would only have to deal with positive numbers. You can reproduce by `=--TEXT(0,"[<1]1;0")`

Comment: @pnuts I assumed from what he wrote, and his short formula example, that values less than `0.5` could also be returned from the long formula, and he would want them rounded to `1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97693/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-pnuts).

Comment: @pnuts  I'll add a statement in my response reconsidering the negative numbers

Comment: crafty indeed! I did, however, misspeak: 0 is a possible value. Negatives are definitely out of the picture. So yes, I want standard rounding (0.5 round up, 0.49 round down), with anything > 0 and < 1 rounding to 1.

Comment: Thank you Ron! Formula works great, solves my issue, and teaches me something new! Trifecta of perfection.

Answer (score 0):

Except for negatives (of which there aren't any) this formula:

```
=(C1<>0)*IF(C1<1,1,ROUND(C1,0))
```

produces the same results as:

```
=IF(AND(C1>0,C1<1),ROUNDUP(C1,0),ROUND(C1,0))
```

and is 15 characters shorter.

It deals with `0` with `(C1<>0)` by returning FALSE when C1 is zero, which the `*` effectively converts to `0`. Otherwise TRUE and then by multiplying by `1` instead of `0` it does not affect the result of the rest of the formula.

The IF statement then tests whether or not C1 is less than `1`. If so, returns `1` and otherwise applies standard rounding (to integers).

The formula might be shortened if the output range were formatted with Cells Format but otherwise anything more succinct is quite likely to be less intelligible - and may be more a matter for [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) than SO.

Though:

```
   =--(TEXT(C1,"[>1]0;[>0]1;0"))
```

is indeed 4 characters shorter still.